# highchart dynamic binding using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I'm trying to bind the data dynamically for comparing One month data two locations line charts.

For this I have created below code it is working good.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Monthly.aspx.cs" Inherits="Monthly" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Monthly Chart</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Details'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: Google.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['12/01/15', '12/02/15', '12/03/15', '12/04/15', '12/05/15', '12/06/15', '12/07/15', '12/08/15', '12/09/15', '12/10/15', '12/11/15', '12/12/15', '12/13/15', '12/14/15', '12/15/15', '12/16/15', '12/17/15', '12/18/15', '12/19/15', '12/20/15', '12/21/15', '12/22/15', '12/23/15', '12/24/15', '12/25/15', '12/26/15', '12/27/15', '12/28/15', '12/29/15', '12/30/15', '12/31/15']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false //enable count
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: false //enable Tooltip on mouse over
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Hyderabad - Location',
                    data: [7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 23, 0, 13, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 17, 16, 14, 10, 6, 4, 5, 9, 25, 24, 23, 60, 34]
                }, {
                    name: 'Chennai - Location',
                    data: [3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 17, 16, 14, 10, 6, 4, 7, 6, 9, 0, 18, 21, 25, 26, 23, 18, 13, 9, 6, 20, 51, 54, 53, 1, 6]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code written statically. Now I want to bind the data dynamically.

How to implement?

Could you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

For us (using VB.net but same overall methodology works) we have a UserControl that calls to get the chart javascript based upon the data that UserControl is responsible for (either from a webservice, ajax call, or old school DTO). It calls a library we wrote that takes the dataset (single series or multi series), size options, and other options we want for this particular chart (such as chart type, title, source footer, etc). From these options we build up the HighCharts `script` tag entries using `StringBuilder`. We then create the `div` to hold the chart using a `literal`. Then we register the client js script we created (using `StringBuilder`) to the page using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)`.

Lots of this is really dependent on your needs specifically and I did not want to get into too much detail because there is a lot going in our system you may/may not need to do.

Another, more "generic" approach is if you have your data you want to plot in an HTML `table` already in your page you can just read directly from the table and add the data to the chart ([example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed)). This, of course, means your asp.net pages already pulled the data into the table.

Yet another approach is to use the new beta of HighCharts .NET (info [here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/197-highcharts-net-wrapper)). This uses MVC.

There are other .NET implementations of HighCharts you can use as well but I have found none satisfactory so we wrote our own.